# How to deal with sqlite database versioning in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, versioning, sqflite

I found `sqlite` database versioning https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper, but I can't find `sqflite` database versioning in Flutter.

I want to ship my app with a prepopulated database and I don't know how to deal with app upgrade version releases for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Preloading data
You might want to preload you database when opened the first time. You can either

[Import an existing SQLite file](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) checking first whether the database file exists or not
Populate data during onCreate:

```
_onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
  // Database is created, create the table
  await db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)");
  }
  // populate data
  await db.insert(...);
}

// Open the database, specifying a version and an onCreate callback
var db = await openDatabase(path,
    version: 1,
    onCreate: _onCreate);
```

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md